# Create a Matrix in RREF with indeterminates in Sage

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sagemath

This quesetion is moreso a programming question involving Sage.

I would like to be able to create a Matrix over a multivariable polynomial ring (in particular over R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'x',(n-k)*n)) in Sage that has a particular form. I would like to create a $k \times n$ matrices that is in RREF form, where I can choose where the pivots should be and fill in the rest with variables from my polynomial ring. (I am assuming full rank, so there will be $k$ pivots with $n \choose k$ possible choices)

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x1  & 0 & x2 & \cdots\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & x3 & \cdots\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots \\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix}$

Is there any way I can do this in Sage by just indicating which columns I want to have the pivots in? I could brute force this by creating a zero matrix that is $k \times n$ then indicating where the pivots are and going entry by entry to determine if I put a variable or not, but I am hoping for a more concise and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this (a while ago) on Ask SageMath: [Create Matrix in RREF with indeterminates](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/47185/create-matrix-in-rref-with-indeterminates/).